# PhpStorm bootstrap autocomplete and warning Unresolved function or method modal()

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, phpstorm

I've got an warning from PhpStorm when i trying to call modal() function from bootstrap.js

> Unresolved function or method modal()

As i understand, PhpStorm don't know anything about this function, so i go to **Preferences > Language & Frameworks > Libraries** , click on Download button and attach bootstrap to project.
That doesn't help me.

This warning affects all bootstrap JS function not only modal().

By the way, there are no autocomplete for bootstrap function.

Modal windows shows and hides well on page. So there are only PhpStorm warning problem.
Thanks for answers.

Comment: What PhpStorm version are you using?

Comment: what library do you use namely? Please share code snippets the issue can be repeated with?

Answer (score 1):

Problem was at minified jQuery lib. After adding non minified version to project everything goes OK.

PhpStorm 2020.2

Maybe that will be useful for someone!

Comment: Completion/types resolving is not reliable then using minified versions on library files, I'd strongly recommend using non-minified, debug versions, or, better, download Typescript library stubs for better coding assistance. This can be done in *Settings | Languages & Frameworks | JavaScript | Libraries, Download...*: type `jquery`  in *Download Libraries* dialog to locate it.
See https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/configuring-javascript-libraries.html#ws_jsconfigure_libraries_ts_definition_files